# Linq Grouping query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, email

```
public class Mailing
{
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string AttachmentPath { get; set; }
    public int AttachmentCount { get; set; }
}
```

giving this structure i have a `IList<Mailing> mailingList` where `To` has dups and the `AttachmentPath` is unique per To.

i need to send emails to the mailingList where each unique `To` has multiple attachments (ie `AttachmentPath`s).

this partially works -- i can get the attachment count and iterate and add attachements as i need but i think this is ugly.  i also need to limit a single email per group of attachments where the below completely breaks.

```
var investorMailings = (from m in mailingList
                       group m by new
                               {
                                   m.GroupBy,
                                   m.To
                               }
                           into g
                           select new DistintInvestorMailing
                               {
                                   To = g.Key.To,
                                   AttachmentCount = g.Count()
                               }).ToList();
```

any ideas?

Comment: please ignore m.GroupBy.  i forgot and left that in.  please disregard m.GroupBy in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var groupedMailings = mailingList.GroupBy(g => g.To);
var investorMailings = groupedMailings.Select(
    g => new 
    { 
        To = g.Key,
        Attachments = g.Select(k => k.AttachmentPath),
        Count = g.Sum(j => j.AttachmentCount) 
    }
);
```

Should Produce an IEnumerable of annonymous types with the following properties:

- **.To** The address to send to
- **.Count** The number of attachments to send
- **.Attachments** an IEnumerable of strings referencing the AttachmentPath's

*Note: Yes this can be turned into 1 linq statement, but i broke it into two for clarity purposes*